# next and previous action

Tags: ios, objective-c

i knew this question is asked many times, but i didn't found any solution for my problem.  I declared counter is 0 on ViewDidLoad,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   counter = 0;
   [stgImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageStr objectAtIndex:counter]]];
}
```

This is my next and previous action,

```
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton*)btn{
   if (btn.tag==1) {
     if (counter < [textStr count]-1) {
        counter++;
        NSLog(@"%i", counter);
        [stgImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageStr objectAtIndex:counter]]];
     }
     if(counter > [textStr count]) {
        counter = 0; //to loop continuously
     }

   }
   else{
     if (counter>0) {
        counter--;
        NSLog(@"%i", counter);
        [stgImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageStr objectAtIndex:counter]]];
     }
   }
```

Problem: This part is not working in my case i.e., there is no continuous loop happened here

```
if(counter > [textStr count]) {
        counter = 0; //to loop continuously
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: use while loop instead of if loop.

Comment: where is your loop u write only condition pls make it as while or something else second typo mistake counterA is not equal to counter

Comment: you are using wrong logic. you are checking if(counter > [textStr count]) and if condition is true then you again set counter = 0.So second time condition is false and loop is not executing continuously.

Comment: @Smita u continue i am moving lunch.....

Comment: sorry for that its counter not counterA

Comment: i tried while (counter > [textStr count]) {
            counter = 0;
        } it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are skipping from `< [textStr count]-1` to `> [textStr count]` and not evaluating equal to. You are also only incrementing your counter in the first for loop so it never gets incremented for your second if statement.

```
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton*)btn{
   if (btn.tag==1) {

     NSLog(@"next clicked");
     NSLog(@"image array count: %i", [imageStr count]);
     counter++;
     if (counter == [textStr count]) counter = 0;
     NSLog(@"counter: %i", counter);
     [stgImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageStr objectAtIndex:counter]]];

   }
   else{

     NSLog(@"previous clicked");
     if (counter>0) {
        counter--;
        NSLog(@"%i", counter);
        [stgImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageStr objectAtIndex:counter]]];
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: if(counter == [textStr count]) is not working, i also tried if(counter == [textStr count]-1) that replace the last image

Comment: the image does not change when i use your simplified code in the above

Comment: 2013-11-15 13:43:01.908 nextandprevious[6939:c07] 0;  just display counter = 0

Comment: There is a problem somewhere else then. The above edits should show where the problem is.

Comment: if i want to display uiview instead of looping.  what to do.

Answer (score 0):

on September 30th I gave you the answer (for those who can see deleted posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087078/i-want-correct-format-of-this-code) as a gist: https://gist.github.com/vikingosegundo/6814617

You must ensure, that both arrays have the same size and that the indices are valid at any time. furthermore you can reduce the code drastically if you use some clever C code as ternary operator and modulo operator.

```
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSAssert([imageStr count] == [txtStr count], @"both arrays need to have the same number of items");
    idx += (button == self.nextButton) ? 1 : -1; // if nextButton increment, else decrement
    idx = idx % [textStr count]; // modolo, will keep idx between 0 and count-1

    [stgImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: imageStr[idx]]];
    stgText1.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textStr[idx]]];
}
```